# create effect when selecting element

Tags: flutter

I'm creating an application in flutter and I need to reproduce the effect shown in the video below.

[video](https://youtu.be/L0r3ghHk8_4)

I remember having done this before, but I don't remember anymore. I've tried looking in several places, but even the search is difficult, because I don't remember how to do it. Can anyone help me reproduce this effect?

Comment: Have you tried asking ChatGPT? I heard it can answer any programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the hover effect on the navigation items?
But you could use an AnimatedContainer and InkWell combination to wrap each item and if you make them reusable Widgets it will make the individual scope of isHovered easy. But you can make use of the InkWell onHover attribute to set a value to trigger animation change

```
AnimatedContainer(
 duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), // Can be whatever duration you want
 curve: Curves.easeInOut, // can be whatever animation you want
 color: isHovered ? Colors.black45 : Colors.transparent,
 child: InkWell(
  onHover: (value) {
   setState(() {
    isHovered = !isHovered;
   });
  },
  child: Widget(),
 ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to be more specific, if the app is on the web or on mobile, if it is on the web you can add a MouseRegion widget and change the color of the button, the name of what you are looking for is onHover

```
MouseRegion(
      onEnter: (_) {
          _buttonColor = true;
      },
      onExit: (_) {
          _buttonColor = false;
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        color: _buttonColor ? Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.8) : Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
```